# JQUERY 3.3.1 AJAX y POST no funciona

Tags: jquery

Editado.

Hola y buenas a todos, tengo problemas con la utilización de $.ajax $.post.
Estoy utilizando JQUERY 3.3.1.

Tengo un form que funciona correctamente, con el id = "formulario" , pero cuando intento utilizar ajax o post, me tira error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#formulario").submit(function(event) {        
  event.preventDefault();
  var direccion   = $(this).attr("action");
  var tipo        = $(this).attr("method");
  var datos       = $(this).serialize();

  $.post( direccion , datos , function(response) {
    $("#resp").html(response);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url : direccion ,
    type: tipo ,
    data: datos
  }).done(function(response){ 
    $("#resp").html(response);
  });

 });
});
```

Utilizando cualquiera de los dos(eliminando uno de los dos o dejando uno de los dos entre comentarios), me tira error en $.ajax o $.post.

Error que aparece con $.ajax o $.post
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Link de la pagina (almacenado en el servidor ftps de la u): 
https://pillan.inf.uct.cl/~jsaa/proyecto/Final/View/registrar.php

busque alguna solución y nada, ni siquiera siguiendo la documentación funciona.

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Se agradece cualquier aporte.

Saludos.

Comment: Click derecho, inspeccionar elemento, pestaña "Network" y mira si se generan las peticiones al servidor. También revisa el tour https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ambos enlaces te serán de utilidad :D

Comment: Dinos cuál es el error, porque decir *me tira error* sin más no da la más mínima idea de qué puede ser. Tienes que usar uno u otro, de preferencia `$.ajax` por ser más completo y permitirte mejor controlar los posibles errores. Y depura los datos en la consola con `console.log(datos);` para verificar si se están recogiendo bien.

Comment: No se vé cual es el error, está muy pequeña la letra, en vez de subir una imagen copia y pega el texto.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez resulte de esta manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formulario").submit(function(event) {        
        event.preventDefault();
        var direccion   = $(this).attr("action");
        var tipo        = $(this).attr("method");
        var datos       = $(this).serialize();

        $.post( direccion , datos)
          .done(function(response) {
              $("#resp").html(response);
          });
    });
});
```

Lo otro, es que a lo mejor deberías tratar de cargar JQuery antes de todo el código, me refiero a poder referenciarlo en la etiqueta "head" en vez de al final del fichero.